# Difference between "react page" naming rule and "react component" naming rule

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code

i was going through a video tutorial on youtube [react web application]... that person in the video was writing file name in small-case "signin.js" [first letter]... component name in small case [first letter]

```
import React from 'react'

const signin = () => {
    return (
        <></>
    )
}

export default signin
```

and was importing it in small case as well

```
import signin from "./signin";
```

but when i do the same thing it gives me error... asks me to name component in upper-case first letter... m confused here... i searched for it on internet but did not get the answer... if anyone can help me understand this, pls... thanking you

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know, all react component must get started with upper-case and it even contains pages(because pages are already components and react-router-dom use them as pages ), you can use lower-case as file-name but you must use upper-case to use it otherwise babel will consider that as html tag and if it's not it will returns error

like this :

```
import Signin from "./signin";
```

but for better readability it would be better to write file name upper-case too

Comment: thanx for answering... i always use uppercase... but in that video he was using lowercase... thus it created doubt in my mind... m i missing anything... @ali

Comment: aha, you were right  ;)

Comment: sure @ali... but that guy was using small-case... i want to know how... hope you understand

Comment: could you please send any photo of that ? it seems to be weired

Comment: https://github.com/a2rp/images/blob/main/lowercase-component-name.png... @ali this is image... as you asked for

Comment: aha, was that working ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import signin from "./signin";
```

If you use it like this, there's a problem with readability,

From signin.jsx

```
const signin = () => {
return (<></>)}
```

You have to write it in lowercase here, too

Instead,

```
import Signin from "./Signin";
```

File name also
Signin.jsx(Extensions are examples)

```
const Signin = () => {
return (<></>)}
```

This is more clearly legible and can reduce errors.

Comment: thanx for the answer @지수박... will you pls explain it to me that can it be done... and if yes, how ???... because i always get error but that video showed small-case... thanking you

Answer (score 0):

Here is the official doc

https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html
also another good resource: https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/react/createElement#caveats

"When an element type starts with a lowercase letter, it refers to a built-in component like  or  and results in a string 'div' or 'span' passed to React.createElement. Types that start with a capital letter like  compile to React.createElement(Foo) and correspond to a component defined or imported in your JavaScript file.

We recommend naming components with a capital letter. If you do have a component that starts with a lowercase letter, assign it to a capitalized variable before using it in JSX."

Comment: by the way @Robert... could you please explain this figure... https://github.com/a2rp/images/blob/main/lowercase-component-name.png

Comment: Explain what???

Comment: in the picture i showed above [the link]... the components are made using first-letter small... if you can then pls explain me that... or i will read your provided link later... m into some office work... thanking you... @Robert